# Java string method to return strings before whitespace

Tags: java

How do I trim a string such as:

```
String str = "Firstname Middlename Lastname"
```

to return only the value of `firstname`

```
str = "Firstname"
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` or `substring` with `indexOf`.

```
str = str.split(" ")[0];
```

or

```
str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" "));
```

In both cases you should add some checks, to avoid errors when the String has no spaces.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies...i got it now.

Usage: writing to file and file name will be firstname.txt

Answer (score 0):

try below code safe and simpler...

`str = str.split(" ")[0];`

Answer (score -1):

you can try this
s.split(" ").length>0?s.split(" ")[0]:System.out.println("wrong input");

Comment: thanks for the check method

Comment: Any reason for down vote?

Comment: @starlord: I can think of three reasons: 1. This duplicates answers posted several minutes earlier. 2. `split` never returns an array with less than one entry, making the `length` check pointless. 3. Splitting twice is inefficient.